# Getting array of Field Names of a class

Tags: java, arrays

I want to get array of field names in the User class. e.g. name,age.

I tried following code -

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();
          ArrayList<Field> utilList = new ArrayList<Field>(Arrays.asList(fields));
           System.out.println(utilList);
    }
}

class User{
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

But it is printing `[java.lang.String prac1.User.name, int prac1.User.age]`.

I need to print `[name,age]` with square bracket Without looping through it.

Square brackets can be attached after and before, but that is not the way I need it.It should come on its own.

Is it possible somehow using overriding `toString` methods?

Comment: Why are you looking to print it without looping through it? If there's a decent reason, use a regex replacement?

Comment: I am not sure, but is it possible some how using `toString()`

Comment: Empirically, `toString()` returns lists of `Object.toString()`. If you need raw name you _must_ either regex-replace the end string or loop through. Regex might hurt you (with the increased computation time).

Comment: `System.out.println(utilList);` calls for utilList.toString(), which  is already using `toString()` of the contained list objects, to show inside []

Comment: ^ Specified by `PrintStream` of `System.out` you can read up on the Oracle docs.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over `utilList` and invoke [Field.getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getName%28%29) on each item.

Comment: first correct ans. One can iterate over the list in any possible way and print in desired format.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 then you can exploit the Functional features to map a list to a new list using a a map function :

```
List<String> mapped = utilList.stream().map(field -> field.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
String[] mapped = utilList.stream().map(field -> field.getName()).toArray();
```

check [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) for more information ,this [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2389/java-8-features-for-developers-lambdas-functional-interface-stream-and-time-api) may help you also.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> utilList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Field field: fields) {
  utilList.add(field.getName());
}
```

But I don't see the point of using utilList…

Comment: This does not work since `Field[]` has no method called `getName`

Comment: Yes I modified my answer. I mis-read it and thought he already done the loop on the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getName` method of `Field`.

```
Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f: fields) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

**Output**

```
name
age
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
Class klass = User.class;
List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Field field: klass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    fieldNames.add(field.getName());
}
System.out.println(fieldNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using Regular Expressions, for reference:

```
// Class
private static final Pattern FIELD_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("(?:[\\dA-Za-z\\.]+) (?:[\\dA-Za-z\\.]+)?\\.([A-Za-z]+)");

// Method
{
    // ...
    Matcher matcher=FIELD_PATTERN.matcher(utilList.toString());
    while(matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$1"));
}
```

You get:

> [name, age]

See the [regex explanation](http://regex101.com/r/tQ5cW2) and try the [code demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/7i).

Oh, and you can build a one-liner out of this:

```
System.out.println(User.class.getDeclaredFields().toString().replaceAll("(?:[\\dA-Za-z\\.]+) (?:[\\dA-Za-z\\.]+)?\\.([A-Za-z]+)", "$1"));
```